# A term for "professional curiosity"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, synonyms

I am looking for a term that describes a specific type of *curiosity*, within the context of one's "profession", or "area of expertise".

In other words, a level of curiosity that is eg. felt by medical researchers looking for a new cure to a known disease, or mathematicians searching for a new formula. A kind of "self-motivated" curiosity.

Comment: I suppose 'dedicated interest' works on various levels, but it's not a fixed phrase.

Comment: "thirst for knowledge", or one of the other entries from http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/curiosity?s=t ?

Comment: @MaxWilliams That's actually a really good answer. Post it and I'll accept!

Comment: I don't think it's really worthy of an answer, given that it's on the thesaurus page, and looking in the thesaurus should be the first step for a question like this.

Comment: @MaxWilliams How noble, to refuse the reward for successfully helping someone. I guess I'll wait until someone else posts it then accept.

Comment: "Abiding interest" is close, and is also idiomatic. But it isn't exclusive to professional interests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Investigative' is as close as can I manage for you.

If there were such a word as 'investigativeness' it would technically fit your actual request, but it would be a cumbersome word to use, I must say.

It's colloquial link to investigative journalism and to forensic work gives it a definite place in a professional context.

> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/investigative

'Analytical' is also possible.

> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/analytical

But I am finding that words which describe professional dispositions seem to attach to the job, not the person.

Analyst and Investigator are the roles involved but we do not have words which state these as qualities in the worker.

An 'analytical mind', yes. An 'investigative disposition,' yes.
But not as noun qualities, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

**Academic interest**

[

> In this document, academic interests and attitudes are defined as a
>   student's relatively stable or enduring predisposition, positive
>   affective orientation, and tendency to persevere when working on
>   certain specific academic content or task domains (Corno et al., 2002;
>   Eccles & Wigfiled, 2002; Renninger & Hidi, 2002).][1](http://www.iapsych.com/acmcewok/Academicinterestsandattitudes.html)